# How to prevent LabelEncoder from sorting label values?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Scikit LabelEncoder is showing some puzzling behavior in my Jupyter Notebook, as in:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le2 = LabelEncoder()
le2.fit(['zero', 'one'])
print (le2.inverse_transform([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```

prints `['one' 'one' 'one' 'zero' 'zero' 'zero']`.
This is odd, shouldn't it print `['zero' 'zero' 'zero' 'one' 'one' 'one']`? Then I tried

```
le3 = LabelEncoder()
le3.fit(['one', 'zero'])
print (le3.inverse_transform([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```

which also prints `['one' 'one' 'one' 'zero' 'zero' 'zero']`. Perhaps there was an alphabetization thing happening? Next, I tried

```
le4 = LabelEncoder()
le4.fit(['nil', 'one'])
print (le4.inverse_transform([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```

which prints `['nil' 'nil' 'nil' 'one' 'one' 'one']`!

I've spent several hours on this. FWIW, the example in [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) works as expected so I suspect there is a flaw in how I expect `inverse_transform` to work. Part of my research included [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870022/inverse-transform-method-labelencoder) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432632/inconsistent-labeling-in-sklearn-labelencoder).

In case it is relevant, I'm using iPython 7.7.0, numpy 1.17.3 and scikit-learn version 0.21.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is that  LabelEncoder.fit() returns sorted data always. That is because it uses `np.unique` Here's the source [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f69242646d239d89a5713982946b8ffcf9d9/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L36)

I guess the only way to do what you want is to create your own `fit` method and override the original one from LabelEncoder.

You just need to reuse the existing code as given in the link, here's example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.utils import column_or_1d

class MyLabelEncoder(LabelEncoder):

    def fit(self, y):
        y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
        self.classes_ = pd.Series(y).unique()
        return self

le2 = MyLabelEncoder()
le2.fit(['zero', 'one'])
print (le2.inverse_transform([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```

gives you:

```
['zero' 'zero' 'zero' 'one' 'one' 'one']
```

Comment: hah ,look what I have just found on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308994/python-sklearn-determine-the-encoding-order-of-labelencoder

Comment: Great find! If you want to edit your answer based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51310759/653651), I'll accept it.